# Python/Shogun Toolbox: Convert RealFeatures to StreamingRealFeatures

Tags: python, shogun

I am using the Python version of the Shogun Toolbox. 
I want to use the `LinearTimeMMD`, which accepts data under the streaming interface `CStreamingFeatures`. I have the data in the form of two `RealFeatures` objects: `feat_p` and `feat_q`. These work just fine with the `QuadraticTimeMMD`.

In order to use it with the LinearTimeMMD, I need to create `StreamingFeatures` objects from these - In this case, these would be `StreamingRealFeatures`, as far as I know.

My first approach was using this:

```
gen_p, gen_q = StreamingRealFeatures(feat_p), StreamingRealFeatures(feat_q)
```

This however does not seem to work: The LinearTimeMMD delivers warnings and an unrealistic result (growing constantly with the number of samples) and calling `gen_p.get_dim_feature_space()` returns `-1`. Also, if I try calling `gen_p.get_streamed_features(100)` this results in a Memory Access Error.

I tried another approach using `StreamingFileFromFeatures`:

```
streamFile_p = sg.StreamingFileFromRealFeatures()
streamFile_p.set_features(feat_p)
streamFile_q = sg.StreamingFileFromRealFeatures()
streamFile_q.set_features(feat_q)

gen_p = StreamingRealFeatures(streamFile_p, False, 100)
gen_q = StreamingRealFeatures(streamFile_q, False, 100)
```

But this results in the same situation with the same described problems.
It seems that in both cases, the contents of the `RealFeatures` object handed to the `StreamingRealFeatures` object cannot be accessed. 
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I was asked for a small working example to show the error:

```
import os
SHOGUN_DATA_DIR=os.getenv('SHOGUN_DATA_DIR', '../../../data')
import shogun as sg
from shogun import StreamingRealFeatures
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import laplace, norm

def sample_gaussian_vs_laplace(n=220, mu=0.0, sigma2=1, b=np.sqrt(0.5)):    
    # sample from both distributions
    X=norm.rvs(size=n)*np.sqrt(sigma2)+mu
    Y=laplace.rvs(size=n, loc=mu, scale=b)

    return X,Y


# Main Script
mu=0.0
sigma2=1
b=np.sqrt(0.5)
n=220
X,Y=sample_gaussian_vs_laplace(n, mu, sigma2, b)

# turn data into Shogun representation (columns vectors)
feat_p=sg.RealFeatures(X.reshape(1,len(X)))
feat_q=sg.RealFeatures(Y.reshape(1,len(Y)))

gen_p, gen_q = StreamingRealFeatures(feat_p), StreamingRealFeatures(feat_q)

print("Dimensions: ", gen_p.get_dim_feature_space())
print("Number of features: ", gen_p.get_num_features())
print("Number of vectors: ", gen_p.get_num_vectors())

test_features = gen_p.get_streamed_features(1)

print("success")
```

EDIT 2: The Output of the working example:

```
Dimensions:  -1
Number of features:  -1
Number of vectors:  1
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

EDIT 3: Additional Code with LinearTimeMMD using the RealFeatures directly.

```
mmd = sg.LinearTimeMMD()
kernel = sg.GaussianKernel(10, 1)
mmd.set_kernel(kernel)
mmd.set_p(feat_p)
mmd.set_q(feat_q)
mmd.set_num_samples_p(1000)
mmd.set_num_samples_q(1000)
alpha = 0.05

# Code taken from notebook example on
# http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/notebook/latest/mmd_two_sample_testing.html
# Location on page: In[16]

block_size=100
mmd.set_num_blocks_per_burst(block_size)

# compute an unbiased estimate in linear time
statistic=mmd.compute_statistic()
print("MMD_l[X,Y]^2=%.2f" % statistic)
```

EDIT 4: Additional code sample showing the growing mmd problem:

```
import os
SHOGUN_DATA_DIR=os.getenv('SHOGUN_DATA_DIR', '../../../data')
import shogun as sg
from shogun import StreamingRealFeatures
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def mmd(n):

    X = [(1.0,i) for i in range(n)]
    Y = [(2.0,i) for i in range(n)]

    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)

    # turn data into Shogun representation (columns vectors)
    feat_p=sg.RealFeatures(X.reshape(2, len(X)))
    feat_q=sg.RealFeatures(Y.reshape(2, len(Y)))

    mmd = sg.LinearTimeMMD()
    kernel = sg.GaussianKernel(10, 1)
    mmd.set_kernel(kernel)
    mmd.set_p(feat_p)
    mmd.set_q(feat_q)
    mmd.set_num_samples_p(100)
    mmd.set_num_samples_q(100)
    alpha = 0.05
    block_size=100
    mmd.set_num_blocks_per_burst(block_size)

    # compute an unbiased estimate in linear time
    statistic=mmd.compute_statistic()
    print("N =", n)
    print("MMD_l[X,Y]^2=%.2f" % statistic)
    print()

for n in [1000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000]:
    mmd(n)
```

Output:

```
N = 1000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-12.69

N = 10000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-40.14

N = 15000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-49.16

N = 20000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-56.77

N = 25000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-63.47

N = 30000
MMD_l[X,Y]^2=-69.52
```

Comment: Shogun's LinearTimeMMD interface accepts features in the form of RealFeatures as well. We handle the conversion to streaming features internally. Can you please try with that and let me know if that works?

Comment: I tried the following code and it worked. But does this also stream the data? I need to use LinearTimeMMD because I am using datasets too large for QuadraticTimeMMD and thus need to be streamed. 

EDIT: Code is in the original post.

Comment: It surely can handle data in streaming fashion. I don't have a Python code ready right now to demonstrate this but here is a unit-test (C++) that uses streaming data generators - https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/develop/tests/unit/statistical_testing/LinearTimeMMD_unittest.cc#L354. If you need, I'll prepare a code-snippet in Python with StreamingFileFeatures and share it with you.

Comment: If you could do that that would be great, thank you! My problem is not about using generators, but about creating the generators from the RealFeatures I have. I also managed to recreate the problem I mentioned in the original post that the linear mmd was growing constantly with the size of the dataset. I added another code sample for that.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the pythonenv in my machine is broken. So, I couldn't give a snippet in Python. But let me point to a working example in C++ which attempts to address the issues (https://gist.github.com/lambday/983830beb0afeb38b9447fd91a143e67).

- I think the easiest way is to create a `StreamingRealFeatures` instance directly from `RealFeatures` instance (like you tried the first time). Check `test1()` and `test2()` methods in the gist which shows the equivalence of using `RealFeatures` and `StreamingRealFeatures` in the use-case in question. The reason you were getting weird results when streaming directly is that in order to start the streaming process we need to call the `start_parser` method in the `StreamingRealFeatures` class. We handle these technicalities internally inside `MMD` classes. But when trying to use it directly, we need to invoke that separately (See `test3()` method in my attached example).
- Please note that the `compute_statistic()` method doesn't return MMD directly, but rather returns `\frac{n_x\times n_y}{n_x+n_y}\times MMD^2` (as mentioned in the doc http://shogun.ml/api/latest/classshogun_1_1CMMD.html). With that in mind, maybe the results you are getting for varying number of samples make sense.

Hope it helps.